# Can an arbitrary-sized constexpr array be used as cases in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, constexpr

Can a variable-sized constexpr array be used in a switch statement so that each arr[i] is a case ? or are if-statements the only solution.

```cpp
constexpr int arr[] = {35, 2, 234, 42, ..., N}; // <------ Random ints
constexpr int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); // <----arbitrary number of elements in array

// want to achieve something like this
switch (var) {
case inArray(var): /* Checks if the var is in the array. Cannot be done at 
                    compile time due to runtime var. Thats why I was looking for a workaround where the switch accepted a range of array values
then expanded it automatically upon compilation */


// other cases

}
```

Sorry just to clarify I am looking for a feature similar to 'case ranges' which is provided by some compilers where they create case statements for you. I am aware that the compiler will know the size at compile time. In my application this size will be changing frequently. I have edited my code above to better reflect the logic I am going for.

Comment: "*variable-sized constexpr array*" There's no such thing. An array with no specified size still has a compile-time determined size. Also, `sizeof(arr)` is not the number of elements in the array.

Comment: I am aware of this, I am asking for something similar to the 'case ranges' which is supported by some compilers. Also in this context sizeof(arr) is the number of elements in the array, feel free to try it.

Comment: Ok I have changed my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The latest VS2019 with standard set to latest accepts the following code:

```
constexpr int arr[]{ 5, 6, 7, 35 };
constexpr int sizeArr{ sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) };
void foo(int v)
{
    switch(v) {
        case arr[0]
        : break;
            case arr[1]
            : break;
                case arr[2]
                : break;
                case arr[sizeArr - 1]:
                    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `constexpr int sizeArr{ sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) };` - I'd personally prefer `constexpr auto sizeArr = std::size(arr);` for that..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but size of array must be computed correctly
E.g. var is made up 99

```
constexpr int arr[] = {35, 2, 234, 42, 99, 67}; // <------ Random ints
constexpr int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) ; // <----arbitrary number of elements in array

int var = 99;

// want to achieve something like this

switch (var) {
case arr[0]:{
    cout<< "0"<<"\n";
    break;
}
case arr[1]:{
    cout<< "1"<<"\n";
    break;
}
case arr[4]:{
    cout<< "4"<<"\n";
    break;
}
case arr[size-1]:
    cout<< size-1 <<"\n";
    break;

}
```

Comment: You could just use `std::size` to get the size.